# Erratic behavior when using unsigned long longs in C/Python program

Tags: python, c

I found a bug in my C program that accepts a numpy array (as a PyObject*) and searches through it for a given value exceeding a threshold. Specifically, if the array is composed of 64-bit ints, the search gives an incorrect result and causes undefined behavior in my code. Here is a simplified version of my code (which supports a variety of array types and equality tests via macros):

```
static void* array_find_ulonglong(PyObject* searchval,
                                  void* start_addr,
                                  void* end_addr,
                                  int stride) {
    unsigned long long value = PyLong_AsUnsignedLongLong(searchval);
    unsigned long long int* i;
    for (i = start_addr; i != end_addr; i+=stride) {
        if (*i >= value) {
            return (void*)i;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

The array has been abstracted into a starting and ending address, and a step (stride) size at which to progress through the memory. The versions of this code for shorter ints work fine, but this version never finds the suitable value (even if it exists in the array) and always returns NULL.

It's also hard to debug because I can't figure out how to print these long long ints. if I supply a Python integer of 3000000 for searchval, then run the following code:

```
printf("%s\n", PyString_AsString(PyObject_Str(searchval)));
unsigned long long value = PyLong_AsUnsignedLongLong(searchval);
printf("%I64u\n", value);
printf("%I64u\n", 3000000ull);
```

I get the output

```
3000000
18446744073709551615
3000000
```

So something seems to be going wrong in the process of unpacking the unsigned long long int from its PyObject representation. I notice in the [Python/C API documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/long.html#PyLong_AsUnsignedLongLong) that PyLong_AsUnsignedLongLong seems to return a value with the unsigned PY_LONG_LONG type, but I get the same results when using this, except the search "finds" (incorrectly) the first element of the array instead of finding nothing. Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: stride is calculated as follows:

```
//arr is the PyArrayObject* passed in from Python via PyArg_ParseTuple
int elsize = arr->descr->elsize;
int stride = arr->strides[0] / elsize;
```

EDIT 2: The error message with which the program crashes is this (some names modified):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Parser.py", line 1893, in <module>
    main()
  File "Parser.py", line 1864, in main
    p.Parse()
  File "Parser.py", line 1411, in Parse
    resultDict = self.ParseField(names, arrays, ignoreMasks, requests)
  File "Parser.py", line 1554, in ParseField
    arrays = Result.CalcAggStat(stat, names, arrays, times, flags, *args)
  File "C:\Users\dpitch40\Documents\Local Sandbox\main\BRANCHES\PARSER3\tools\integrated\Parser\DFiles\Result.py", line 1503, in CalcAggStat
    for name, array, t, flag in zip(names, arrays, times, flags):
SystemError: ..\Objects\longobject.c:980: bad argument to internal function
```

I have played around with the section that crashes. Each of the lists being zipped together in the failing line has one element. So the loop being run runs through one iteration (in which the C searching code given above is run), then it crashes with the above error when it comes *back* to the line with the **for**. The line number in longobject.c is part of an error handling function of some kind, so the message seems mostly useless.

Comment: Guess: `stride` is measured in bytes, but `i+=stride` increments `stride * sizeof(*i)`.  Either change `stride` calculation or `i+=stride`.  I'd go for `stride /= sizeof(*i)` or something like that.  Need to see more code for best direction.

Comment: I have already tested it with smaller int sizes and it works then. I would expect this problem to affect arrays with 2 and 4-byte elements. See my calculation of stride above; this is not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Claris' suggestion to look for errors that may have occurred, I first tried calling perror(), which printed "No error". Then I checked if any Python exceptions had been thrown and found that the error message I was getting (shown above) originated in the searching code I posted, but for some reason hadn't been getting shown until the **for** line. So the "bad call to internal function" in longobject.c happened in some of my code handling unsigned long long ints, which made sense.

I then tried adding these checks to my program:

```
printf("Is int: %d\n", PyInt_Check(searchval));
printf("Is EXACTLY int: %d\n", PyInt_CheckExact(searchval));
printf("Is long: %d\n", PyLong_Check(searchval));
```

Which printed the following output:

```
Is int: 1
Is EXACTLY int: 1
Is long: 0
```

So while the values of the array I was searching through were long long ints, the search value I was supplying from Python was not, which caused the error when trying to convert it into a C unsigned long long. (I thought Python integers and longs were more interchangeable than that, but apparently not) So I added a check for the type of the array in the Python wrapper for my C code, and if it contains 8-byte integers the search value is converted into a Python long. This seems to have fixed the problem. Thanks for the help and probing questions.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
for (i = start_addr; i != end_addr; i+=stride) {
```

to

```
for (i = start_addr; i != end_addr; i+=1) {
```

recall that 1+ void* is next element in list, or type cast better:

```
for (i = start_addr; i != end_addr; ((uint8_t*)i)+=stride) {
```

Also

18446744073709551615 = -1 or FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

Comment: Sorry, I should have included the code for how stride is calculated, which takes this into account. Added to my original post. As I said, the problem appears to be when I try to convert the value being searched for from a PyObject* into an unsigned long long int. Do you know what I am doing wrong with this?

Comment: You are most likely getting an error (based on your return code). Does perror provide any useful information?

Comment: Sorry, could you elaborate? The return code from which function? Do you mean after Python crashes?

Comment: No, after trying to do the conversion, you get -1. Does perror("") show anything? Also, you may find scipy.weave easier to use or at least helpful in debugging some of this. I.e. examine the executable generated by scipy.weave when you are doing the same operations.

Comment: Oh, I see, I made a mistake when checking the binary form of that number so I missed that. Using perror prints "No error", though. Then I realized that it might have set an error message for Python to give. So I tried having the top-level C function return NULL (to indicate that an error occurred) and got the same error message, only from the execution of the C searching function. It seems this error has always been occurring, and it just wasn't printed until the for line for some reason. So I assume it has to do with me mishandling long long ints somehow.

Comment: I may have found the issue: using the PyInt_CheckExact function it seems that searchval is of the type PyInt_Type and not PyLong_Type. That seems to have produced the correct behavior.

Comment: Numpy arrays are C arrays. Perhaps you don't need to do the conversion or you are doing the wrong conversion? I can't tell exactly what is going on here.

Comment: I'm glad you found your answer